# Mapping applications using a NoSQL datasource?

Tags: nosql, gis

I've been using Geoserver with a postgis datasource but I was thinking of switching over to a NoSQL solution for storing my geospatial data since the schemaless nature of NoSQL databases fits my application well.

However, it seems that most mapping applications that I've come across (geoserver, mapserver) don't have support for NoSQL datastores.  The closest thing I've come accross is [couchmaps](https://github.com/normanb/couchmaps)

Has anyone used NoSQL for mapping?  If so, what tools have you used?  What I'm looking for in particular is an application that can serve WMS and WFS requests using a NoSQL datastore.

Comment: I heard someone say that the fastest NoSQL solution he had benchmarked was a single two column (key/value) table in Postgres.  NoSQL is as much a development methodology as a technology.

Answer (score 0):

for GIS data and Search in Nosql MongoDB is suitable for you because mongodb itself provide facility to store and search for GIS data.

read more at [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing)

Answer (score -1):

I am interested in the same issue, and it seems that GeoServer is ready to work with MongoDB as seen in http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-geoserver.
I hope this could help you too, http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/mapping-worldcup-opengeo-suite-mongodb/ . It explains how to configure the connection between GeoServer + MongoDB and how to add a layer using geotweets as source information.

Comment: Please add some content to your answer. If the link ceases to be valid, your answer will not be able to help anyone.